# Matrix as a 2D probability distribution: get the central moments

Tags: matlab, matrix, distribution, probability

I have got a matrix which gives me a 2-dimensional discrete distribution (N²->R) in Matlab.

Are there built-in functions in Matlab (R2011b, with the statistic toolbox) giving the central moments and the mean? If they exist for functions of (R²->R) it is fine too. Otherwise I will have to build them myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look and I couldn't turn up any functions, though this isn't a fact by any means.

However, working it out from scratch, and assuming you mean a matrix such as:

```
    % x=1  x=2  x=3
P = [ 0.1  0.2  0.1        % y = 1  
      0.1  0.1  0.2        % y = 2
      0.0  0.0  0.2 ]      % y = 3
```

And you mean that this describes the joint discrete distribution (joint probability mass function).  That is, the entry at `(X,Y)` contains the probability of `(X,Y)` occurring.

I'm also assuming by your use of `N` in mathematical notation means the natural numbers.  If so, then you can use the following code.

Mean:

```
 meanX = sum(P,1) * (1:size(P,2))'; 
 meanY = sum(P,2)' * (1:size(P,1))';
```

For the central moment `K,L` (`K` correspnding to `X` and `L` corresponding to `Y`):

```
 [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(P,2),1:size(P,1));
 integrandXY_KL = (X - meanX).^K .* (Y-meanY).^L .* P;
 momentXY_KL = sum(integrandXY_KL(:));
```

And you can generalize it further if the values of X are arbitrary (and not just natural numbers) as follows.  If  `Xvals = [ 1 2 4 ]` and `Yvals = [ 4 5 6 ]`.  All of the above still works, you just replace all occurences of `1:size(P,2)` with `Xvals` and all occurences of `1:size(P,1)` with `Yvals`.